# Will child JVM "inherit" max heap size and perm gen size when forked?

Tags: maven, jvm, heap-memory, fork, permgen

If I specify a given max heap size and perm gen size in an exported shell variable i.e. `JAVA_OPTS` or `MAVEN_OPTS` and the Maven build forks the JVM, will the child JVM "inherit" or attempt to access the same configuration as the parent JVM, when I run my build from the shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, they won't inherit. This is a common problem with Maven plugins; they usually have a parameter (e.g. surefire's `argLine`) that lets you specify what JVM options you want.